# Xcode info.plist file deleted

Tags: xcode, file

Unforunately, I deleted the info.plist file of my xcode project. I still have a file called Info.plist.xml.
Can I generate the info.plist file from that?
It looks like that:

https://s12.postimg.org/w1rqw7f19/Unbenannt.png

What can I do to get the file back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plist` is an xml file. If the content is right, you can reuse it. Just remove ".xml" part.

You can create another dummy project and compare your *info.plist.xml* to the *info.plist* of the dummy to check the content.